# custom markers in google map api

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

iam currently working on a google map api app

here is my code

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    Button zin,zout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
//        zin = findViewById(R.id.zin);
//        zin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
//            }
//        });
//        zout = findViewById(R.id.zout);
//        zout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut());
//            }
//        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
        if (mFusedLocationClient != null) {
            mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(120000); // two minute interval
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(120000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Location Permission already granted
                mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
                mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else {
                //Request Location Permission
                checkLocationPermission();
            }
        }
        else {
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            List<Location> locationList = locationResult.getLocations();
            if (locationList.size() > 0) {
                //The last location in the list is the newest
                Location location = locationList.get(locationList.size() - 1);
                Log.i("MapsActivity", "Location: " + location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude());
                mLastLocation = location;
                if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
                    mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
                }
//
//                //Place current location marker
//                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
//                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
//                markerOptions.position(latLng);
//                markerOptions.title("Current Position");
//                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
//                mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                //move map camera
//                mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 11));
            }
        }
    };

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    private void checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                        .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // location-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
                        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }
}
```

now i have 2 question , first how can i add buttons on the map ? not below and not above , same as google map application

second how can i add custom marker , for example here is this app
[app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMF1G.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4zU9.png)

how can i reach that ?
thank you

Comment: This may help you: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker

Comment: Another approach: https://www.trulia.com/blog/tech/custom-map-markers-for-android-google-maps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question about buttons in the map, i suppose that you are talking about the info window. You can reach that setting a CustomInfoWindowAdapter to the google map with the Custom View. I will give you a basic example follow your images, later adapt it to your needs. I hope that this can help you!

First we need a view to show in the info window:

**infowindow_layout.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Saint Anthony Catedral for"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="02440A"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/gm_icon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/materialButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="See departures"
        app:cornerRadius="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/materialButton2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/materialButton2"
        app:strokeWidth="4dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/materialButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Recharge Hafilat"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/materialButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:strokeColor="@color/blue" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/to"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TO"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/from"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/from"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/from" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/from"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="FROM"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/to"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/x"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Let's create now the custom adapter:

**CustomInfoWindowAdapter.java**

```
class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    private Context context;

    public CustomInfoWindowAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        View view = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.infowindowlayout, null);

        return view;
    }
}
```

And finally let's set it to the google map in the **onMapReady()** method:

```
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        //(...)
        this.googleMap = googleMap;
        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowGoogleMap(requireActivity()));

    }
```

Now you have a custom info window :)

For the **CustomMarker** you just need to add a custom icon using GoogleMap's **IconGenerator** object:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fire_truck);
imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.whiteTextColor));

Icon generator of google maps
IconGenerator generator = new IconGenerator(context);
generator.setContentView(imageView);
generator.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
Bitmap markerIcon = generator.makeIcon();

googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
         .position(position)
         .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(markerIcon))
         .draggable(true)
);
```

The both results are this:
[image: Final result]